# How to show the error messages caught by assertRaises() in unittest in Python2.7?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In order to make sure that the error messages from my module are informative, I would like to see all the error messages caught by assertRaises(). Today I do it for each assertRaises(), but as there are lots of them in the test code it gets very tedious.

How can I print the error messages for all the assertRaises()? I have studied the documentation on http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html without figuring out how to solve it. Can I somehow monkeypatch the assertRaises() method? I prefer not to change all the assertRaises() lines in the test code, as I most often use the test code the standard way.

I guess this question is related to [Python unittest: how do I test the argument in an Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883357/python-unittest-how-do-i-test-the-argument-in-an-exceptions)

This is how I do it today. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def fail():
    raise ValueError('Misspellled errrorr messageee')
```

And the test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest
import failure   

class TestFailureModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def testFail(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, failure.fail)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

To check the error message, I simply change the error type in the assertRaises() to for example IOError. Then I can see the error message:

```
 E
======================================================================
ERROR: testFail (__main__.TestFailureModule)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test_failure.py", line 8, in testFail
   self.assertRaises(IOError, failure.fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 471, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/jonas/Skrivbord/failure.py", line 4, in fail
    raise ValueError('Misspellled errrorr messageee')
ValueError: Misspellled errrorr messageee

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Any suggestions?
/Jonas

**EDIT:**

With the hints from Robert Rossney I managed to solve the problem. It is not mainly intended for spelling errors, but for making sure that the error messages are really meaningful for the user of the module. The normal functionality of unittest (this is how I use it most of the time) is achieved by setting SHOW_ERROR_MESSAGES = False.

I simply override the assertRaises() method, as seen below. It works like charm!

```
SHOW_ERROR_MESSAGES = True

class NonexistantError(Exception):
    pass

class ExtendedTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertRaises(self, excClass, callableObj, *args, **kwargs):
        if SHOW_ERROR_MESSAGES:
            excClass = NonexistantError
        try:
            unittest.TestCase.assertRaises(self, excClass, callableObj, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print '\n    ' + repr(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

A fraction of the resulting output:

```
testNotIntegerInput (__main__.TestCheckRegisteraddress) ... 
    TypeError('The registeraddress must be an integer. Given: 1.0',)

    TypeError("The registeraddress must be an integer. Given: '1'",)

    TypeError('The registeraddress must be an integer. Given: [1]',)

    TypeError('The registeraddress must be an integer. Given: None',)
ok
testCorrectNumberOfBytes (__main__.TestCheckResponseNumberOfBytes) ... ok
testInconsistentLimits (__main__.TestCheckNumerical) ... 
    ValueError('The maxvalue must not be smaller than minvalue. Given: 45 and 47, respectively.',)

    ValueError('The maxvalue must not be smaller than minvalue. Given: 45.0 and 47.0, respectively.',)
ok
testWrongValues (__main__.TestCheckRegisteraddress) ... 
    ValueError('The registeraddress is too small: -1, but minimum value is 0.',)

    ValueError('The registeraddress is too large: 65536, but maximum value is 65535.',)
ok
testTooShortString (__main__.TestCheckResponseWriteData) ... 
    ValueError("The payload is too short: 2, but minimum value is 4. Given: '\\x00X'",)

    ValueError("The payload is too short: 0, but minimum value is 4. Given: ''",)

    ValueError("The writedata is too short: 1, but minimum value is 2. Given: 'X'",)

    ValueError("The writedata is too short: 0, but minimum value is 2. Given: ''",)
ok
testKnownValues (__main__.TestCreateBitPattern) ... ok
testNotIntegerInput (__main__.TestCheckSlaveaddress) ... 
    TypeError('The slaveaddress must be an integer. Given: 1.0',)

    TypeError("The slaveaddress must be an integer. Given: '1'",)

    TypeError('The slaveaddress must be an integer. Given: [1]',)

    TypeError('The slaveaddress must be an integer. Given: None',)
ok
```

Comment: Why continue to use assertRaises if you need to check the arguments?  Why not simply catch the exception and examine it using `try`  and `except`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Out-of-the-box `unittest` doesn't do this.  If this is something you want to do frequently, you can try something like this:

```
class ExtendedTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def assertRaisesWithMessage(self, msg, func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      func(*args, **kwargs)
      self.assertFail()
    except Exception as inst:
      self.assertEqual(inst.message, msg)
```

Derive your unit test classes from `ExtendedTestCase` instead of `unittest.TestCase`.

But really, if you're simply concerned about misspelled error messages, and concerned enough to want to build test cases around it, you shouldn't be inlining messages as string literals.  You should do with them what you do with any other important strings:  defining them as constants in a module that you import and that someone is responsible for proofreading.  A developer who misspells words in his code will also misspell them in his test cases.

Comment: +1 for "A developer who misspells words in his code will also misspell them in his test cases."

Comment: To me, it's far more egregious when you are testing to see that a _specific_ error is occurring, but a test can 'pass' due to unintended side effects.  E.g. the error you expected didn't get raised, but the same error type is raised elsewhere, thus satisfying the test.  The test passes, the code is bugged.  Same deal for errors that subclass the error you're looking for -- if your test is too general, you end up catching something you don't expect.

Comment: You should use

    ``inst.args[0]``

instead of

    ``inst.message``

to run this code both on Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: This is not true, out of the box unittest does do this.

Comment: Neato example of subclassing. But I have a hard time believing this is necessary or advantageous, as `unittest`'s 'out of the box' capabilities are quite extensive.

Comment: @JonathanHartley - I'm also seeing this as the default behavior with unittest in Python3.  Any exception which is caught by assertRaises will be magically printed to stdout along with a stacktrace, even if the tested code never logs or prints anything.

The only way which I've found works to suppress this is by setting the root logger level to logging.CRITICAL.  This is strange because, as stated, nothing is being logged or printed in the test, or the code which it's testing.  This workaround also prevents all other logging messages as well, so it's not a practical solution.

Comment: @AlexJohnson Strange. Thanks for telling me. I'll go investigate and amend my comments...

Answer (score 177):

I once preferred the most excellent answer given above by @Robert Rossney. Nowadays, I prefer to use assertRaises as a context manager (a new capability in unittest2) like so:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as cm:
    failure.fail()
self.assertEqual(
    'The registeraddress must be an integer. Given: 1.0',
    str(cm.exception)
)
```

Comment: NB. assertRaises can be used as a context manager from 'unittest' in Python 2.7. unittest2 backports features for earlier versions of Python. http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: What if , the code fails at the "with" part....in my case , that with part fails...so i want to show a message ..like we can do for other plain asserts e.g self.assertEqual(cm.exception.faultCode,  101001, 'Fault code does not match expected fault code %d' % 101001)

Comment: @arindamroychowdhury, I'm sorry, but I haven't coded any Python in quite some while so I don't know the answer to your question.  Best of luck. Perhaps, one of the other people here could better answer your question. Good luck.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7. I had to replace str(cm.exception) with cm.exception.parameter.

Comment: This answer isn't wrong, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/16282604/6419007 is probably much better.

Answer (score 84):

You are looking for [assertRaisesRegex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex), which is available since Python 3.2. From the docs:

```py
self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "invalid literal for.*XYZ'$",
                       int, 'XYZ')
```

or:

```
with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, 'literal'):
    int('XYZ')
```

PS: if you are using Python 2.7, then the correct method name is `assertRaisesRegexp`.

Comment: yes, but if expected error is not risen, you will never see the message/cannot change the default one. Extremaly uncomfortable when testing some parameters in loop - you don't know for which parameter the function pass through without expected error.

Comment: On python 3.6, it is saying `DeprecationWarning: Please use assertRaisesRegex instead` when using `with self.assertRaisesRegexp( RuntimeError, '...regex...' )`

Comment: This is excellent. Concise, very powerful and much more precise than simply testing for some Exception.

Answer (score 45):

If you want the error message exactly match something:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as error:
  do_something()
self.assertEqual(error.exception.message, 'error message')
```

Comment: I had to use `str(error.exception)` instead of `error.exception.message` as `error.exception` has no `message` attribute in my case.

Answer (score 7):

mkelley33 gives nice answer, but this approach can be detected as issue by some code analysis tools like [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com). The problem is that it doesn't know that `assertRaises` can be used as context manager and it reports that not all arguments are passed to `assertRaises` *method*.

So, I'd like to improve Robert's Rossney answer:

```
class TestCaseMixin(object):

    def assertRaisesWithMessage(self, exception_type, message, func, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except exception_type as e:
            self.assertEqual(e.args[0], message)
        else:
            self.fail('"{0}" was expected to throw "{1}" exception'
                      .format(func.__name__, exception_type.__name__))
```

Key differences are:

1. We test type of exception.
2. We can run this code both on Python 2 and
   Python 3 (we call `e.args[0]` because errors in Py3 don't have
   `message` attribute).

Comment: This is a very elegant solution IMO. In case you don't like `e.args[0]`, you could also invoke `str(e)`.