# Testing exception message with assertRaise

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to assertRaise the exception inside a function where a condition raises a custom exception message .

Function:

```
if not Cart.objects.filter(member=member).count():
    raise CartDoesNotExist("Cart Does Not Exist for Member: %s ( %id )." % (member.email,member.id))
```

Now , i am able to successfully produce the required condition to get to the raise statement.

So , my testcase looks like this :

```
def Order_CartDoesNotExist(self):        
  self.assertRaises(CartDoesNotExist,Order.objects.create_order(member=self.member2,member_slot=self.memslot,order_type="Normal"))
```

When i run the test , the output is an Error . It gives the same error CartDoesNotExist.....

So my question is , how to raise these kind of exceptions ? How to cover these situations in our unittest? I do not want to escape these conditions as they are important and increase code coverage?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is calling create_order directly, which raises the exception.  You need to change how it is called.  In Python 2.7, you can use this:

```
with self.assertRaises(CartDoesNotExist):
    Order.objects.create_order(member=self.member2, member_slot=self.memslot, order_type="Normal"))
```

Here the context manager allows you to call your code directly, and the context manager will handle the exception for you.

If you are running with 2.6 or below:

```
self.assertRaises(CartDoesNotExist, Order.objects.create_order, member=self.member2, member_slot=self.memslot, order_type="Normal")
```

Here you aren't calling your function, you are passing it to assertRaises, along with the arguments it needs, and assertRaises will call the code and deal with the exception properly.

Comment: That worked instantly......Thank you sir.....Is there a way to check the output message "Cart does not exist for........" ?

Comment: @arindamroychowdhury see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672754/how-to-show-the-error-messages-caught-by-assertraises-in-unittest-in-python2-7) for some tips on getting the exception details.