# Python Unit Test Dictionary Assert KeyError

Tags: python, python-unittest

I wasn't sure how to create a Python unittest to check if a dictionary returned a KeyError. I thought the unit test would call the dictionary key so it would look like this:

```
def test_dict_keyerror_should_appear(self):
    my_dict = {'hey': 'world'}
    self.assertRaises(KeyError, my_dict['some_key'])
```

However, my test would just error out with a **KeyError** instead of asserting that a KeyError occurred.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371849/testing-exception-message-with-assertraise#11371899

Answer (score 7):

To solve this I used a `lambda` to call the dictionary key to raise the error.

```
def test_dict_keyerror_should_appear(self):
    my_dict = {'hey': 'world'}
    self.assertRaises(KeyError, lambda: my_dict['some_key'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem):

```
from operator import getitem

self.assertRaises(KeyError, getitem, my_dict, 'some_key')
```